# What is the fastest way a client can communicate with a WCF service?

Tags: performance, wcf

What is the fastest way a client can communicate with a WCF(Windows Communication Foundation) Service if both are hosted in the same private network?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF - what is the fastest binding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191416/wcf-what-is-the-fastest-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is [NetTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you are on two seperate machines.

If you host your service on the same machine as the client, [Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be even faster.